# How do I pass arguments to shell script?

Tags: unix, batch-file, shell, dos

I have a batch file like this:

```
java temptable %1 %2
```

I need the equivalent shell script for the above. I will pass the arguments to the shell script and that should be passed to temptable.

Comment: Here is an article, How to pass arguments to a shell script. It covers most about
command line arguments [How to pass arguments to a shell script](http://bashscript.blogspot.com/2009/11/how-to-pass-arguments-to-shell-script.html)

Answer (score 19):

For bash (which is *one* shell, but probably the most common in the Linux world), the equivalent is:

```
java temptable $1 $2
```

assuming there's no spaces in the arguments. If there are spaces, you should quote your arguments:

```
java temptable "$1" "$2"
```

You can also do:

```
java temptable $*
```

or:

```
java temptable "$@"
```

if you want all parameters passed through (again, that second one is equivalent to quoting each of the parameters: "$1" "$2" "$3" ...).

Comment: That is also valid for sh and all derived shells, not just bash (AFAIK)

Comment: I didn't want to speak for jsh/rc/rsh/tcsh/zsh/csh/ksh/bash/ash/sh/*sh and assume they were all the same.

Comment: The sh/ksh/bash family are quite similar. I believe zsh to be closer to (ba|k)?sh than to the csh family.

Answer (score 10):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Call this script with at least 3 parameters, for example
# sh scriptname 1 2 3
echo "first parameter is $1"
echo "Second parameter is $2"
echo "Third parameter is $3"
exit 0
```

Output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# sh parameters.sh 47 9 34
first parameter is 47
Second parameter is 9
Third parameter is 34
```